# Convert RDD of Array[Array[String]] to DataFrame

Tags: arrays, scala, apache-spark, dataframe, rdd

I have a dataset in the `RDD` format, where each entry is an `Array[Array[String]]`.
Each entry is an array of `key/value` pairs, and each entry may not contain all possible keys.

An example of a possible entry is `[[K1, V1], [K2, V2], [K3, V3], [K5, V5], [K7, V7]]` and another might be `[[K1, V1], [K3, V3], [K21, V21]]`.

What I hope to achieve is to bring this `RDD` into a dataframe format. `K1`, `K2`, etc. always represent the same `String` over each of the rows (i.e. `K1` is always "type" and `K2` is always "color"), and I want to use these as the columns. The `values` `V1`, `V2`, etc. differ over rows, and I want to use these to populate the `values` for the columns.

I'm not sure how to achieve this, so I would appreciate any help/pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like,

```
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Row, SparkSession}
import java.util.UUID
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType

    val l1: Array[Array[String]] = Array(
      Array[String]("K1", "V1"),
      Array[String]("K2", "V2"),
      Array[String]("K3", "V3"),
      Array[String]("K5", "V5"),
      Array[String]("K7", "V7"))

    val l2: Array[Array[String]] = Array(
      Array[String]("K1", "V1"),
      Array[String]("K3", "V3"),
      Array[String]("K21", "V21"))

    val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local").getOrCreate()
    val sc = spark.sparkContext

    val rdd = sc.parallelize(Array(l1, l2)).flatMap(x => {
      val id = UUID.randomUUID().toString
      x.map(y => Row(id, y(0), y(1)))
    })

    val schema = new StructType()
      .add("id", "String")
      .add("key", "String")
      .add("value", "String")

    val df = spark
      .createDataFrame(rdd, schema)
      .groupBy("id")
      .pivot("key").agg(last("value"))
      .drop("id")

    df.printSchema()
    df.show(false)
```

The schema and output looks something like,

```
root
 |-- K1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- K2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- K21: string (nullable = true)
 |-- K3: string (nullable = true)
 |-- K5: string (nullable = true)
 |-- K7: string (nullable = true)

+---+----+----+---+----+----+
|K1 |K2  |K21 |K3 |K5  |K7  |
+---+----+----+---+----+----+
|V1 |null|V21 |V3 |null|null|
|V1 |V2  |null|V3 |V5  |V7  |
+---+----+----+---+----+----+
```

Note: this will produce `null` in missing places as shown in outputs. `pivot` basically transposes the data set based on some column
Hope this answers your question!